# Как задать background тексту в виде изображения?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет!

Подскажите, как реализовать (css/html/js) данный эффект текста так, чтобы фоном текста было изображение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо!

Comment: Не легче ли в фотошопе запилить?

Comment: а если нужно заднее изображение двигать при необходимости...?

Comment: Есть background-clip, но оно работает только в webkit

Comment: может что на js есть?

Comment: текст будет меняться? если нет то можно png с прозрачными буквами и двигайте заднюю сколько хотите

Comment: есть вариант с рисованием текста на canvas, текст можно вроде залить  прозрачным цветом. сам не делал. вот нашел  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223894/partially-transparent-opacity-html5-canvas-drawings ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359537/how-to-change-the-opacity-alpha-transparency-of-an-element-in-a-canvas-elemen  читай

Comment: Да, текст будет меняться. Благодарю, изучаю.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Товарищ [user202854](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/202854/user202854) указал верное направление для 'раскопок', в итоге задуманное получилось реализовать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
  ctx.font = 'bold 80px sans-serif';
  ctx.fillText("Image text", 20, 80);
};
img.src = 'https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/81/Russia_Mountains_Lake_469922.jpg';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```